# Use Laravel 5 Form Request validation with related models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using (and loving) the Laravel 5 form request validation so far. But now I'm stuck trying to validate related models.

Say I have a `Car` model which has many `Wheel` models and I'd like to validate a new car. In the `CarController@store` method I'm using the following to validate the car, but this does of course not validate the wheels.

```
public function store(StoreCarRequest $request)
{
   // Create the car
}
```

What needs to be done to validate the `Wheel`s of a `Car`? Can this be done with form request validation?

**Edit**

I'm getting closer. The remaining issue is that I need to iterate through the wheels which are stored in an array (because the HTML input name is e.g. `wheels[0][color]`), but the validator is searching for a `color` field, not `wheels[0][color]`.

```
public function store(StoreCarRequest $r)
{
    // Validate the wheels
    foreach ($r->input('wheels') as $wheel)
    {
        // TODO: use $wheel somewhere?
        $snr = new StoreWheelRequest;
        $this->validate($r, $snr->rules()); // Validation fails: 'color' field is required
    }

    // Validation passed, create the car (and the wheels)
}
```

*StoreCarRequest.php*

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'engine' => 'required',
        'seats'  => 'required',
    ];
}
```

*StoreWheelRequest.php*

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'color' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

*The HTML form*

```
<form method="POST" action="...">
    <input type="text" name="engine">
    <input type="text" name="seats">
    <input type="text" name="wheels[0][color]">
    <input type="text" name="wheels[1][color]">
    <input type="text" name="wheels[2][color]">
    <input type="text" name="wheels[3][color]">
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

Comment: What goes wrong with your code?

Comment: Also would you please provide your HTML form?

Comment: I added the form to the question. The problem is that the validation fails, because it looks for a `color` field (which does not exist) and tells that it is required. The color field is actually `wheels[id][color]`.

Comment: Why are you creating 2 Form Requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more Googling, I stumbled upon the following article: http://ericlbarnes.com/laravel-array-validation/

It boils down to adding rules dynamically inside the `rules()` method by iterating over the input array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dot notation to validate nested arrays :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'engine' => 'required',
        'seats'  => 'required',
        'wheel.color'  => 'required',
    ];
}
```